# LibreOffice won't open in Pop-OS

Tags: libreoffice

I'm using pop-os 19.10 with gnome 3.34.2 and whenever I try to launch libreoffice(version 6.3.4) I get this error:
`/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2: undefined symbol: FT_Get_Var_Design_Coordinates`

I tried removing ~/.config/libreoffice.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling libreoffice from the pop!_shop and with these commands:

`sudo apt-get --purge remove libreoffice-core`

`sudo apt-get install libreoffice`

I also downloaded .appimage of two older versions(5.4.0 and 6.2.8). It gives the same error when I try to run them.

When I run any them with sudo it works. However this "locks" the files I'm working on since it changes the owner of the file to root every time I save.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It seems obvious that libcairo version is not compatible with the version of libreoffice you have. If your distro has only one version of those available, then I would recommend filling a bug. But maybe you're using some unofficial repositories which pulled wrong version into your system?

Comment: No, I don't think I'm using any unofficial repositories. How can I check the version of libcairo?

Comment: Check out this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/428772/how-to-install-specific-version-of-some-package
However, I don't think you should care about the version. Package maintainers should take care about compatibility of the packages.